# Почему правильно — НЕПРЕРЫВНО

Tags: орфография, частица-не

Почему НЕ пишется слитно, хотя это слово употребляется без НЕ?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В словаре есть прилагательное "прерывный".

ПРЕРЫВНЫЙ,  =Прерывистый. П. разговор. П-ое строение электричества. <Прерывность, -и; ж. П. производственного процесса. П. спектра.

Наречие "прерывно" используется, но не часто и в основном в текстах, относящихся к первой половине 20 века: Сначала молчал, потом начал говорить что-то **бессвязно, прерывно**. [А. В. Чаянов. Юлия, или Встречи под Новодевичьим (1928)]

**Но даже не в этом дело.** Если слово не употребляется без НЕ, то оно пишется всегда **слитно.**

Но если оно употребляется без НЕ, то может писаться **как слитно, так и раздельно, например:** большой, небольшой, не большой, очень небольшой, не большой, а маленький, отнюдь не большой и т.д.